# Shared layer visualization with TensorBoard

Tags: keras, tensorboard

Using the functional API, I specified a complex model. I reuse this model several times like specified:

```python
def build_model():
   # build a model
   model = Model(..., name="complex_model")
   return model

complex_model = build_model() # return a Keras model
input_a = Input(...)
input_b = Input(...)
inst_a = complex_model(input_a)
inst_b = complex_model(input_b)
merged = ... # merge inst_a, inst_b
output = Dense(..., name="last_dense")(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=output)
model.compile(...)
model.fit(..., callbacks=...) # see below for callbacks
```

I want to visualize the weights of some layers using TensorBoard. This can easily be done for the *last_dense* layer like

```python
ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(..., embeddings_freq=1, embeddings_layer_names=["last_dense"])
```

But how can I access a layer that is inside the complex model?
Say I want to access a layer called *first_dense*, neither of the following works:

```python
ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(..., embeddings_freq=1, embeddings_layer_names=["first_dense"]
ks.callbacks.TensorBoard(..., embeddings_freq=1, embeddings_layer_names=["complex_model/first_dense"]
```

Instead, it throws an

```python
ValueError: No variables to save
```

Is it ever possible to access this layer and if yes, how?